# Search for a company in Facebook pages

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I`m writing an application in PHP which searches for a company on different social platforms (Facebook, Google+) by name, address, ZIP and phone number. The most important for me now, is Facebook. What I found so far, is
Graph API search functionality:

```
/search?q={COMPANY_NAME}&type=page
```

But this only uses company name as search parameter. Any ideas how we could do this also by using name, address, ZIP and phone number as search fields?

Comment: I'd say use the Google Search API with the following query: site:facebook.com COMPANYDATA

Comment: Can you give a few details and not just a fair phrase please?

Comment: Search by address is not directly available via API; you can search for “places” however via lat/long – so if you convert the address into those coordinates via another service, that might work.

Answer (score 0):

Found something, finally.
Search on Facebook can be made by company name using Graph. The result looks something like this:

```
{
  "data": 
  [
    {
      "category": "Company", 
      "category_list": [
      {
        "id": "209889829023118", 
        "name": "Landmark"
      }
  ], 
  "name": "Pixar", 
  "id": "107673092595794"
 }
```

}

Then you can make a request by id, in this case `107673092595794` to access the address, phone number or any additional data about company.